# Error on including a file - Warning: include(connect.php): failed to open stream: No such file or director

Tags: php, include

Here is the image of project file structure -

[image]

I added `include 'connect.php'` in index.php file.

Index.php file is present in register folder. But i get an error 'failed to open stream no such file'.

Comment: it should be `include '../connect.php'`

Comment: tried this? include '../connect.php'

Comment: @Simon_eQ thnx, it worked. I was adding single '.' earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a simple `DOCUMENT_ROOT` to your include in which way it will always go for the direct server path to the file.

```
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/connect.php";
```

Comment: @MohitChawla I don't like the tone of your comment. I looked at your picture and accidently wrote the folder in to my reply when it's pretty obvious it is not in, even though if i would not look at your image. Be grateful that people are willing to help you out instead of accusing them of not paying attention in this example. A simple "hey thanks but you made a small mistake there ..." would have sufficed.